# Haskell ST Monad: No instance for (MArray (STArray s) Int (ST s1))

Tags: haskell, monads, st-monad, starray

I have been learning Haskell for the past month or two, and recently solved [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-duplicates-in-an-array/description/) coding problem. The additional challenge was to do the task without extra space and in linear time, which I did not think would be possible to do in a purely functional way, so naturally I found out about the ST monad and I thought this would be a good opportunity to learn more about it. Anyways, here is the code that I wrote:

```
module FindDuplicates where

import Control.Monad (foldM)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST

xs = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1] :: [Int]

findDuplicates :: [Int] -> ST s [Int]
findDuplicates xs = do
    arr <- newListArray (1, length xs) xs :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)

    let go :: [Int] -> Int -> ST s [Int]
        go acc i = do x <- abs <$> readArray arr i
                      y <- readArray arr x
                      if y < 0
                          then return (x:acc)
                          else do writeArray arr x (-y)
                                  return acc 

    foldM go [] [1..length xs]
```

The idea is to use the pre-condition that 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n and that each element appears at most 2 times. But the code gives me the following error.

```
FindDuplicates.hs:14:36:
    No instance for (MArray (STArray s) Int (ST s1))
      arising from a use of ‘readArray’
    In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘readArray arr i’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- abs <$> readArray arr i
    In the expression:
      do { x <- abs <$> readArray arr i;
           y <- readArray arr x;
           if y < 0 then
               return (x : acc)
           else
               do { writeArray arr x (- y);
                    .... } }
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `No instance for (MArray (STArray s) Int (ST s1))`, the most important thing to notice is that it's talking about two different type variables, `s` and `s1`.  There is no instance of `MArray` unless those two type variables are the same.  This is an important part of how `ST` is valid with an externally-pure interface.

The reason the compiler thinks that there are two different type variables involved is that you put a type signature on `go`.  The type variable `s` in that signature is not the same as the type variable `s` in the signature of `findDuplicates`.  This is an inherent part of Haskell's type signature rules - type variables in any particular signature are unrelated to type variables in any other signature.

The simplest way to fix this is to remove the signature from `go`. Type inference will get the correct type for it.

If you want to get fancier, you can use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension to allow the signature on `go` to share the type variable with the enclosing definition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module FindDuplicates where

import Control.Monad (foldM)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST

xs = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1] :: [Int]

findDuplicates :: forall s. [Int] -> ST s [Int]
findDuplicates xs = do
    arr <- newListArray (1, length xs) xs :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)

    let go :: [Int] -> Int -> ST s [Int]
        go acc i = do x <- abs <$> readArray arr i
                      y <- readArray arr x
                      if y < 0
                          then return (x:acc)
                          else do writeArray arr x (-y)
                                  return acc 

    foldM go [] [1..length xs]
```

The `LANGUAGE` pragma at the top enables the extension.  To use the extension, you need to specify the type variables in a definition with `forall`.  (Forgetting to do that is the most common reason for `ScopedTypeVariables` to fail to work.)

After doing that in the type of `findDuplicates`, it stores that `s` in scope across the entire definition.  When finding the type variable `s` in the type of `go`, it no longer treats it as a fresh type variable, and makes it match the type `s` in the enclosing context instead.

Comment: That's very interesting! Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ZaferCesur, I love `ScopedTypeVariables`, but if you don't want to use it, another option is to make `go` take the array as an argument.